# error while building android 4.3 master

Tags: android, javac, ubuntu-10.04, android-build

i need to build android 4.3 master. following instruction from here http://source.android.com/source/building.html . It's going well up to sync-ing source code from repo.
When we are trying to build using "make -j4", this is occurring.

```
1 error
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Here is full log -

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.3.2.1.000.000
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_panda
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a9
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-2.6.32-38-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-10.04-lucid
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE panda
target Java: core (out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core_intermediates/classes)
host Executable: aidl (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl)
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/AaptAssets.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/Command.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/CrunchCache.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/FileFinder.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/Main.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/Package.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/StringPool.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/XMLNode.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ResourceFilter.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ResourceIdCache.cpp
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ResourceIdCache.cpp:10:0:
frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ResourceIdCache.h:10:16: warning: declaration 'class     android::String16' does not declare anything [enabled by default]
frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ResourceIdCache.cpp: In static member function 'static void     android::ResourceIdCache::dump()':
frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ResourceIdCache.cpp:101:40: warning: format '%ld' expects argument of type 'long int', but argument 2 has type 'std::map<unsigned int, CacheEntry>::size_type {aka unsigned int}' [-Wformat]
frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ResourceIdCache.cpp:102:34: warning: format '%ld' expects     argument of type 'long int', but argument 2 has type 'size_t {aka unsigned int}' [-Wformat]
frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ResourceIdCache.cpp:103:36: warning: format '%ld' expects argument of type 'long int', but argument 2 has type 'size_t {aka unsigned int}' [-Wformat]
frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ResourceIdCache.cpp:104:46: warning: format '%ld' expects argument of type 'long int', but argument 2 has type 'size_t {aka unsigned int}' [-Wformat]
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ResourceTable.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/Images.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/Resource.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/SourcePos.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ZipEntry.cpp
host C++: aapt <= frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ZipFile.cpp
host StaticLib: libandroidfw (out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libandroidfw_intermediates/libandroidfw.a)
host C++: libutils <= frameworks/native/libs/utils/BasicHashtable.cpp
host C++: libutils <= frameworks/native/libs/utils/BlobCache.cpp
host C++: libutils <= frameworks/native/libs/utils/BufferedTextOutput.cpp
host C++: libutils <= frameworks/native/libs/utils/CallStack.cpp
libcore/luni/src/main/java/libcore/reflect/AnnotationAccess.java:743: type parameters of <A>A cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable A with upper bounds A,java.lang.annotation.Annotation
    return AnnotationFactory.createAnnotation(annotationClass, members);
                                             ^
host C++: libutils <= frameworks/native/libs/utils/Debug.cpp
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ResourceTable.cpp:11:0:
frameworks/base/tools/aapt/ResourceIdCache.h:10:16: warning: declaration 'class android::String16' does not declare anything [enabled by default]
```

Any insight or help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what is your jdk version? can check with

```
$java -version
```

mine is **1.6.0_26**

I had the same error as you when I install **jdk-6u24-linux-x64.bin** from oracle. After I switch to **jdk-6u26-linux-x64.bin**, the error is gone, not sure if it is the same case as you.

Comment: yes, after shuffling some java installation and re-syncing, i am able to build now. The problem was with java version for sure, though i am using 1.6.0_45 now, i am accepting your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "shuffling some java installation"? How did you solve the problem?