# Android source code compilation error

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to compile the android source code. I am getting this error.

```
libcore/luni/src/main/java/libcore/reflect/AnnotationAccess.java:695: 
type parameters of <A>A cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance
exists for type variable A with upper bounds ,java.lang.annotation.Annotation
return AnnotationFactory.createAnnotation(annotationClass, members);
                                             ^
host C: libcrypto_static <= external/openssl/crypto/asn1/x_req.c
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
host C: libcrypto_static <= external/openssl/crypto/asn1/x_sig.c
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core_intermediates
/classes-full-debug.jar] Error 41
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I did source build/envsetup.sh 
then used lunch aosp_arm-eng, then finally make -j4. 
Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: So, you have used search and found [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714349/error-while-building-android-4-3-master) and [this android-building group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/8Z5bAN7M07w), but it does not provide a solution in your case?

Comment: mine is java version "1.6.0", will update and check...

Comment: After updating to java version "1.6.0_45" (Both java and javac), it seems to be working. Thanks.